# Regarding shell script -env variables

Tags: unix, shell

Have a shell script that reads the files in a particular directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
for fspec in /exp/dira/test/ready/* ; do
done
```

I want to modify the unix shell script so that path is retreived from enviornmental variable.

`export CUST_DATA=${_FX_DATA_}/test`   have  set this variable in environment thru .profile

```
#!/bin/bash
READY_FILES= "$CUST_DATA/ready"
for fspec in $READY_FILES/* ; do
done
```

i tried the above but it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working', exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space after the equal sign makes it mean something completely different.

```
#!/bin/bash
READY_FILES="$CUST_DATA/ready"
for fspec in "$READY_FILES"/* ; do
  ....
done
```

Comment: Good use of quotes to work even if `$READY_FILES` contains whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #!/bin/bash
    . ~/.profile
    READY_FILES="$CUST_DATA/ready"
    for fspec in $READY_FILES/* ; do
     ...
    done
```

Comment: Should quote `"$READY_FILES"` in the `for` statement.  Always quote variables unless you have a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

add `echo "<$CUST_DATA>"` to your second script to make sure that variable is not set.